# How to install linux-modules-extras in a Ubuntu 18.04 docker image?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04, usbserial, ftdi

I have a problem setting up a Docker image that interacts with a USB device on `Ubuntu 18.04`. I get the following errors when running the `rmmod` command in a script run from within the container to begin interacting with this USB device:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module ftdi_sio is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module usbserial is not currently loaded
```

I have got this to work when running the image from a machine running `Ubuntu 20.04` by installing `linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic` in the Docker image. However, when I try to install the equivalent (`linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-143-generic` I think) in the Docker image running on `Ubuntu 18.04` I get the following error when trying to build the image:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-143-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-143-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-143-generic'
```

Maybe I’m just trying to install the wrong thing? I’ve also tried installing `linux-modules-4.15.0-143-generic` but this gives the same error. Any ideas where I’m going wrong?

***EDIT:*** It may be relevant to note that whilst I want to run my Docker image on a `Ubuntu 18.04` machine, it is actually running a `Ubuntu 20.04`-based image. I guess that, because the running container inherits the host machine kernel, I need the corresponding `linux-modules-extra` version installed in the image which would be `4.15.0-143-generic`?

Comment: You pretty much can't interact with kernel modules from inside a container, for a couple of reasons.  You need to manage those from the host.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is confusing because when I run the Docker image from my `Ubuntu 20.04` machine I can install `linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic` and use `lsmod` in the container to show that the `ftdi_sio` and `usbserial` modules exist and I can connect to my USB device. This just isn't the case on my `Ubuntu 18.04` machine.

Comment: Kernel modules are extremely specific to the kernel they're built for.  If your image has a module built against the Ubuntu `5.8.0-53-generic` kernel but the system has any other kernel at all -- the host has taken a patch release, you're running on a different Linux distribution, a different Ubuntu kernel variant is installed -- it won't run.  You also need to disable some important security controls to be able to `lsmod` from within a container.  Since it's so specific to the host it's running on, this needs to be done from the host system and not a container.